# Unhealthy backends using GCP network endpoint groups for container-native Load Balancing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

we're testing out google's new [container-native load balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/)feature. We followed this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/container-native-load-balancing) successfully, and we're trying to roll it out to our three services on GKE.

As far as I can tell, the only difference between the NEG feature and the legacy GCLB ingress object is the annotations in each service so the URL mapping should work the same.

We've updated all of the services to use this annotation but two out of three are `Unhealthy` while one is considered healthy. The only differences in the service yamls are the name and selector.

All of the deployments have health checks and are healthy when we inspect manually but the LB says the backends are unhealthy.

What are we missing?

`Ingress.yaml`

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: fanout-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "neg-ip"
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: frontend-svc
    servicePort: 8080
  rules:
  - host: testneg.test.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: frontend-svc # Healthy service
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /backend/*
        backend:
          serviceName: backend-svc # Unhealthy service
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /notifications/*
        backend:
          serviceName: notifications-svc # Unhealthy service
          servicePort: 8080
```

--

`frontend-svc.yaml` - backend/notifications are same except for name and selector

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend-svc
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}' # Creates an NEG after an Ingress is created
spec:
  selector:
    app: frontend
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
```

--

`backend-deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  minReadySeconds: 60
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        image: us.gcr.io/<OUR_DJANGO_IMAGE>
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: backend
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        readinessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          periodSeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 3
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          periodSeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 3   
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
```

Answer (score 2):

your ingress yaml file show different services

```
- path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: frontend-svc # Healthy service
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /backend/*
        backend:
          serviceName: backend-svc # Unhealthy service
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /notifications/*
        backend:
          serviceName: notifications-svc # Unhealthy service
          servicePort: 8080
```

Your frontend-svc.yaml has a different service name "li-frontend-svc" which is not in your ingress.

The Spec.Backend.serviceName in your ingress should match the same as your service name, the unhealty backend service is expected.

last edit:

in your ingress you specify two time the service frontend-svc, you should use the ingress spec as follow spec:

```
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: first-service # Name of the Service targeted by the Ingress
          servicePort: 8080 # Should match the port used by the Service
        path: <first-service-path>/*
      - backend:
          serviceName: second-service # Name of the Service targeted by the Ingress
          servicePort: 8080 # Should match the port used by the Service
        path: <second-service-path>/*
      - backend:
          serviceName: third-service # Name of the Service targeted by the Ingress
          servicePort: 8080 # Should match the port used by the Service
        path: <third-service-path>/*
```

Here my reproduction:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    run: neg-hello-1 # Label for the Deployment
  name: neg-hello-1 # Name of Deployment
spec: # Deployment's specification
  minReadySeconds: 60 # Number of seconds to wait after a Pod is created and its status is Ready
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: neg-hello-1
  template: # Pod template
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: neg-hello-1 # Labels Pods from this Deployment
    spec: # Pod specification; each Pod created by this Deployment has this specification
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0 # Application to run in Deployment's Pods
        name: neg-hello-1 # Container name
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080 # Port used by containers running in these Pods
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 15
          periodSeconds: 20
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60 # Number of seconds to wait for connections to terminate before shutting down Pods
```

---

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    run: neg-hello-2 # Label for the Deployment
  name: neg-hello-2 # Name of Deployment
spec: # Deployment's specification
  minReadySeconds: 60 # Number of seconds to wait after a Pod is created and its status is Ready
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: neg-hello-2
  template: # Pod template
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: neg-hello-2 # Labels Pods from this Deployment
    spec: # Pod specification; each Pod created by this Deployment has this specification
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:2.0 # Application to run in Deployment's Pods
        name: neg-hello-2 # Container name
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080 # Port used by containers running in these Pods
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 15
          periodSeconds: 20
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60 # Number of seconds to wait for connections to terminate before shutting down Pods
```

--

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: neg-hello-1 # Name of Service
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}' # Creates an NEG after an Ingress is created
spec: # Service's specification
  selector:
    run: neg-hello-1 # Selects Pods labelled run: neg-hello-1
  ports:
  - port: 80 # Service's port
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
```

--

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: neg-hello-2 # Name of Service
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}' # Creates an NEG after an Ingress is created
spec: # Service's specification
  selector:
    run: neg-hello-2 # Selects Pods labelled run: neg-hello-2
  ports:
  - port: 80 # Service's port
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
```

--

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: neg-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: neg-hello-1 # Name of the Service targeted by the Ingress
          servicePort: 80 # Should match the port used by the Service
        path: /*
      - backend:
          serviceName: neg-hello-2 # Name of the Service targeted by the Ingress
          servicePort: 80 # Should match the port used by the Service
        path: /v2/*
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - just a typo on stackoverflow, which I've corrected. They do indeed match as the frontend service is the only one that returns healthy.

Comment: you can check my answer i did modify it accordingly, make sure you leave at least 15 min for the ingress to be created

Comment: The first time I specify the frontend-svc it is to declare the default backend. Without it, the LB creates a new backend that routes to no services. Nonetheless, I tired your suggestion, waited 20 minutes, and the same two services are considered unhealthy, despite the GKE readiness and liveness probe showing otherwise. I should note that the original ingress.yaml file works great without the NEG feature. I think this is very likely a bug with the GCE loadbalancer and NEG.

Comment: Hello Mike@, I did succeed to create a neg cluster with 2 service running with ingress I can modify my answer to add the yaml file that I used, let me know

Comment: Thanks @alioua - though, there is almost no difference between our yamls. The only difference is that my deployment specifies readiness and liveness checks on the containerPort. Otherwise, services + ingress are identical and still have the same issue.

Comment: ok, how did you configure your livenessProbe is it httpGet or tcp socket or exec, it's better to add your deployment and I will check where it's stuck (for sure your issue belong to the healtcheck probs)

Comment: tcp socket. Just edited my question to include the backend deployment yaml. The backend service yaml is identical to frontend-svc, just different names/selectors. Thanks for looking!

Comment: that weird I did add tcp socket in my two service and there are working fine the only exception is I did add a "timeoutSeconds" and replicas set, you are exposing the services on 8080 did you try changing it and verify?

Comment: add to my answer the liveness and readiness prob, and working as expected, the I'm using the default heath check in my load balancer "/healthz"

Comment: One thing  that I remember is the services should be a NodePort type

Comment: thank you for your patience and help. Well, I really botched this one. I had a setting in my application code that was blocking the IPs from the health checks. Totally forgot about it. Once I cleared that, the loadbalancer works fine.